# Is it possible to migrate apps individually from one mac system to another?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I have filemaker installed on my Snow Leopard machine, and I have a fresh Lion install. I'm looking into using the user migration tool - But it doesn't allow selection of apps, it's either all or nothing. I have a lot of crap that I want to get rid of, and I thought there must be a way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're migrating to one machine to another... And you have means of accessing eachother (file sharing, firewire link or even usb disk), you can just copy the apps you need to the new system.

If you're using a media that's not mac native format, be sure to ZIP the applications before transporting them, but if you're doing it via network (shared folder), just copy it from the origin to the destination!

You won't have all the configurations copied tough... But if you want to copy those too, you'll have to take a look at the `~/Library` and `~/Library/Application Preferences` for any folders with the same name of your app (usually) and copy them too.